# Conceptual understanding of variable scope in higher order functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, higher-order-functions

I have a function `score0` which gives me a score for every turn (for `n` turns) in a loop. This score is incremented by a random integer from 1 to 15 every turn.

I now have to design another higher order function which should print the highest score jump of a player out of all the score jumps yet, and should be called inside the `score0` function. I name it `highest_gain`. Naturally, this should print the first score value as it's the first turn (hence it is the biggest jump).

```
# Function that defines the highest point jump in a score yet
import random
def highest_gain(previous_value, highest_point):
    def say(score) :
        if previous_value == 0:
            print ('Biggest gain by player0 yet with',score,'points!') 
            return highest_gain(score, score) 
        gain = score - previous_value
        if gain > highest_point:
           print('Biggest gain by player0 yet with',score,'points!') 
           return highest_gain(score, gain)
    return say

# Function that gives me a new score (incremented) every turn    
def score0(n, score = 0):
    while n > 0:
          score += random.randint(1, 15)
          highest_gain(previous_value = 0,highest_point = 0)(score)
          n -= 1
    return score

#Calling the function   
score0(4,0)
```

[Python Tutor link](https://pythontutor.com/composingprograms.html#code=import%20random%0A%0Adef%20highest_gain%28previous_value,%20highest_point%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20say%28score%29%20%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20previous_value%20%3D%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%20%28%27Biggest%20gain%20by%20player0%20yet%20with%27,score,%27points!%27%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20highest_gain%28score,%20score%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gain%20%3D%20score%20-%20previous_value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20gain%20%3E%20highest_point%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28%27Biggest%20gain%20by%20player0%20yet%20with%27,score,%27points!%27%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20highest_gain%28score,%20gain%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20say%0A%20%20%20%20%0Adef%20score0%28n,%20score%20%3D%200%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20while%20n%20%3E%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20score%20%2B%3D%20random.randint%281,%2015%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20highest_gain%28previous_value%20%3D%200,highest_point%20%3D%200%29%28score%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20n%20-%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20return%20score%0A%20%20%20%20%0Ascore0%284,0%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=0&mode=display&origin=composingprograms.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D)

The problem is that calling `highest_gain()` doesn't update the values of `previous_value` and `highest_point`. Why aren't these variables getting updated in the `score0()` function body, and how should `highest_gain()` be called be called so that these variables are updated on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: For clarity, where do you believe the variables *should* be updated?

Comment: It should be updated in the ```score0``` function body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `highest_gain` function is a higher-order function which returns another function named `say`. When `say` is called, it calls `highest_gain` again and returns the result, which is - again - the function `say`. The important point here is that `say` is a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) over the local variables of the outer function `highest_gain`, so each time `highest_gain` is called you get a different instance of the `say` function, with different values of the outer function's local variables.

Now, since calling `say` returns another instance of `say` which closes over the updated values, that means you need to keep the result from when you call it, so you can call the new instance which closes over those updated values.

```py
def score0(n, score=0):
    say = highest_gain(previous_value=0, highest_point=0)
    while n > 0:
          score += random.randint(1, 15)
          say = say(score) or say
          n -= 1
    return score
```

I moved the original call of `highest_gain` to before the loop, since you don't want to use the initial values of `0` on every iteration.

Note that `say` doesn't *always* return a new instance of `say` - sometimes it returns `None`, so I used the trick `say(score) or say` here so that `say` keeps its old value if there isn't a new one to update it with. You could alternatively write this as below, which is more verbose but perhaps makes clearer what this is doing:

```py
new_say = say(score)
if new_say is not None:
    say = new_say
```

Otherwise, you could change the definition of `say` so that it returns itself (i.e. with the current values of the variables from the outer function) when there should be no update, and then in `score0` you could just write `say = say(score)`.

Comment: This was tremendously helpful! As someone who's only beginning to learn this stuff I cannot overstate how big of a learning gap was just filled because of having this concept cleared up.